# Problems accessing Context.xml Mail resource in OpenShift

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift, jakarta-mail

Please help,
I have a Java Spring MVC application (Tomcat 7) on OpenShift which is trying to use a resource lookup in Context.xml. I keep getting 500 errors when it tries to create the session `session = (Session) envContext.lookup("mail/Session");` ( see code below ). There are no exceptions in the logs in app-root/logs/jbossews.log, `e.printStackTrace();` doesn't print anything in the catch block. Do exceptions get logged somewhere else perhaps? I'm used to having a access.log and error.log in apache/tomcat, jbossews.log doesn't see to tell me anything (FYI I am not using RHC tools, I'm just tailing the log over ssh).

My project runs fine on my local system in eclipse with no issues. 
Please help,
Thanks

```
Session session = null;

Context initalContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initalContext.lookup("java:comp/env");


try{
    // Blows up here with a 500 error
    session = (Session) envContext.lookup("mail/Session");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // No StackTrace printed
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my resource located in jbossews/conf/context.xml

```
  <Resource
      name="mail/Session"
      type="javax.mail.Session"
      auth="Container"
      mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
      mail.smtp.socketFactory.port="465"
      mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
      mail.smtp.auth="true"
      mail.smtp.port="465"
      mail.from="XXXXXX@mailserver.com"
      mail.user="XXXXXX@mailserver.com"
      password="XXXXXX"
      />
```

I tried adding the following to my web.xml to see if that would fix the problem (It didn't).

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Resource reference to a factory for javax.mail.Session   instances that may be used for sending electronic mail messages, preconfigured to connect to the appropriate SMTP server.</description>
    <res-ref-name>mail/Session</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that you [shouldn't need to set a socket factory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll look into that. Nobody seems to have any advise :(

Comment: You  might have better luck on a JBoss forum or mailing list, or if you add a jboss tag to this post.

Comment: Looks like you need socket factory after all for gmail at least. From my localhost will only work with the socket factory.

Comment: Did you set `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to `true`?

Comment: Ah ok, it works when I add mail.smtp.ssl.enable.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue was due to an issue in my pom.xml (Not related to accessing Context.xml after all). Annoyingly Exceptions weren't being logged in jbossews.log so I had to explicitly log them via `Exception exception = (Exception) httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        exception.printStackTrace(); ( httpRequest being a HttpServletRequest Object)`

The problem in my pom.xml was this, I tried using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Using the following dependency solved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: In order for the Context.xml "mail/Session" resource to work on OpenShift I had to create a lib folder in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ and place javax.mail-api.jar inside.

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing problems.